# Vertex shader matrix multiplication broken?

Tags: android, c++, opengl-es, opengl-es-2.0, vertex-shader

OpenGL ES 2.0 on Android: A very simple shader that works on a almost all devices, but doesn't on a Huawei Ascend P6:

vertex shader:

```
attribute vec2 a_position;
attribute vec2 a_texcoords;

uniform mat4 u_matrix;

varying mediump vec2 v_texcoords;

void main()
{
    gl_Position = u_matrix * vec4(a_position, 0.0, 1.0);
    v_texcoords = a_texcoords;
}
```

fragment shader:

```
uniform lowp sampler2D u_textureUnit;

varying mediump vec2 v_texcoords;

void main()
{
    gl_FragColor = texture2D(u_textureUnit, v_texcoords);  
}
```

The shader program is used to draw squares in the z=0 plane (as 4-vertex triangle strips) and a_position is given in world space. a_texcoords are standard (0,0)->(1,1) coordinates. u_matrix is set from a perspective camera, i.e. projectionmatrix*viewmatrix. when i change the distance in the view matrix (zooming in), at one point the tiles disappear, and only the clear color is shown, as if the fragment shader was never executed. when i zoom out again, i see tiles again.

Now the weird thing starts: when i (in the C++ code) transform the position to clip space and pass it to the shader as an `attribute vec4` and write it unmodified to `gl_Position`, everything works as expected on the Huawei device. I have also compared the results of `u_matrix * vec4(a_position, 0.0, 1.0)` with the clip space position that i passed, and it turns out that they are *almost* equal to the clip space coordinates that i pass in from the cpu side. (in fact, i did the perspective division on both and then emitted `vec4(1)-vec4(abs(difference).xyz*20.0,0.0)` as a color - it was barely differentiable from white, so the difference is very small, i guess just different floating point arithmetics.)

any idea what's going on? scissor, depth and stencil tests are disabled, near and far planes of the camera are fine, backface culling is disabled. Feel free to ask for more detail...

update1: if i tilt the cam to not look exactly in -Z, i get the same artifact, but it looks like near-plane-clipping now (i can zoom in to a state where only half the screen is blank). But i have no idea how this can happen; my near plane is set to 20 (meters); but the artifact happens at a camera <-> z=0 plane distance of ~1300 (meters).

Comment: To be honest, you should be using a `vec4` vertex attribute for your position anyway. All vertex attributes in GL are inherently 4-component per-location (a `vec2` attribute occupies 1 location). You do not gain anything by declaring your position as `vec2`, you wind up having to write an extra * `vec4 (..., 0.0, 1.0)` when you want to multiply it by `u_matrix` that you would not if you let GL handle expansion from 2D to 4D automatically. GL assigns `Z` a value of **0.0** and `W` a value of **1.0** if you write `attribute vec4` and then give that attribute enough data for only 2 components.

Comment: True, but that doesn't change anything about the actual problem - I just tried to be absolutely sure. it works only if i do the transformation on the cpu - any thoughts about why this could be the case?

Comment: The only thing that comes to my mind immediately is that on the CPU-side, single-precision floating-point probably means 32-bit. In GLES, `highp` can actually have as few as 16-bits. The Vivante GC4000 GPU in that phone is capable of 32-bit FP though, so I would expect the default precision in the vertex shader (`highp`) to use the full precision. If you declare `precision float mediump` in the vertex shader on your other devices, does this behavior pop up there as well?

Comment: I tried with mediump on several devices, it seems to work fine on all of them - but the spec says that mediump may be equal to highp, and i don't have a way to find out if it actually is on a device. I tried with lowp as well, which still works on a Nexus 4 (because there probably even lowp==highp), but doesn't on a Nexus S (where mediump works). I also discovered something else - see update1

Comment: Have you tried specifying `highp` precision in *fragment* shader?

Comment: for the varying? or globally? but i can tell you without trying that this doesn't change anything - the problem also occurs with the simplest shader ever: `void main( gl_FragColor = vec4(1); }`